# how to make the size of loader big without CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, bulma

```
  <div class="loader-wrapper ">
      <div class="loader is-loading"></div>
        </div>
```

[Loader image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFJQZ.png)

I want to to increase the size of the loader without added anything in CSS!

Comment: Please edit the question and do NOT write in capital.

Answer (score 0):

<img src="your_image.jpg" **width**="500" **height**="600">

Answer (score 0):

**in component**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loading',
  template: `
    <div #loaderWrapper class="loader-wrapper ">
      <div class="loader is-loading"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('loaderWrapper') loaderWrapper: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderWrapper.nativeElement.style.with = 500;
    this.loaderWrapper.nativeElement.style.height = 500;
  }
}
```